# Function to check for Memory Allocation Errors

Tags: c, realloc

My program has a bunch of pointers such as

```
int* one;
int** two;
int*** three;
```

and I want to check for memory allocation errors while using realloc on them. I know that realloc returns `NULL` if the allocation fails so I made the following function:

```
void checkMemoryAllocationError(const void *a){
   if (a == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr, "Realloc failed");
      exit(5); //5 is arbitrary
   }
}
```

Can I call this function in the following way?

```
checkMemoryAllocationError(one);
...
checkMemoryAllocationError(two);
...
checkMemoryAllocationError(three);
```

or does the fact that two and three are pointers to pointers make a difference? I would rather not have an if statement in my body of code repeatedly so does this solution work or is there a better way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: Note that having many instances of a pointer to a pointer to a pointer is a sign that the program could be improved. You generally don't want to be a [Three Star Programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling a separate checking function, you could wrap it around `malloc()`:

```
void *check_malloc(size_t size) {
    void *result = malloc(size);
    if (result == NULL) {
        printf(stderr, "Realloc failed");
        exit(5); //5 is arbitrary
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then call `check_malloc()` instead of calling `malloc()` directly.

You can make similar wrappers around `realloc()` and `calloc()`.